# how to map data inside data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous

I map through data array fetched from API.
I have an array  (speciality) inside the data array. but info is not rendered. no errors

```
const CardItem = ({ data = [] }) => {
    console.log(data, 'mapping')
    return (
        <>
            { data.map(item => {
                return (
                    <Col lg={4} md={6} sm={12} xs={12} key={item.id}>
                        <Card>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.avatar} />
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title>{item.firstName} {item.lastName}</Card.Title>
                                <Card.Text>
                                    <ul>
                                        {Array.isArray(item.specialty) && item.speciality.length > 0 && item.speciality.map((i) => {
                                            return (
                                                <li>{i}</li>
                                            )
                                        }) : null}
                                    </ul>
                                </Card.Text>
                                <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </Card>
                    </Col>
                )
            })}
        </>
    )
}

export default CardItem
```

Comment: Can you change your condition to `item.speciality && item.speciality.length > 0 && renderLogic()`. Also, can you please attach a JSON for how your `item` looks. The `speciality` might be a `object` rather than `array`.

Comment: When it says `item.speciality.map is not a function`, my immediate question is, "well, then what *is* it?".  Most likely if `map` is not a function then it is `undefined`.  So if you have `item.speciality.length > 0` is true, but `item.speciality.map` is undefined, then in all likelihood `item.speciality` is a **string**.  You should do some debugging, or logging to determine what its type is, and why it's a string instead of an array.  Maybe you forgot to `JSON.parse` something and it's still in string format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explicitly check for type `Array` you can check with `Array.isArray(var)`

```
{Array.isArray(item.specialty) && item.speciality.length > 0 ? item.speciality.map((i) => {
return (
   <li>{i}</li>
)
}) : null}
```